# how can we make users to restrict the delete records in professional edition

Tags: administration

In professional edition how do we restrict the users to delete records please help me out of this

Answer (score 1):

Without custom profiles, you can't restrict users from deleting records they own in Professional Edition.

You can purchase custom profiles without upgrading to Enterprise Edition. This is less expensive than a full upgrade.

Answer (score 1):

You can override the delete button with a Visualforce page, even in Professional Edition.  It just cannot have a custom controller.  Something like this would work.

`<apex:page action="{!if($User.Alias !='Enter User Alias Here',
    null,
    urlFor($Action.Account.Delete, $CurrentPage.Parameters.id, [retURL='/001'], true)
    )
    }"
  standardController="Account">
   <apex:pageBlock >
        <apex:PageMessage summary="You are not allowed to delete Accounts"
            severity="Warning"
            strength="3"/>
        <apex:pageMessages />
  </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:page>`

This would allow you to put your user alias in to the formula, so you could delete Accounts if needed.